# Sum of floored fractions $\lfloor \frac{1^3}{2009} \rfloor + \lfloor \frac{2^3}{2009} \rfloor + \cdots + \lfloor \frac{2008^3}{2009} \rfloor$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I want to compute the remainder of $A$ divided by 1000, where $A$ is

$$A = \lfloor \frac{1^3}{2009} \rfloor + \lfloor \frac{2^3}{2009} \rfloor + \cdots + \lfloor \frac{2008^3}{2009} \rfloor.$$

I tried to observe the number of $x$'s that satisfies $\lfloor \frac{x^3}{2009} \rfloor = k$, for each $k$. However this turned out to be hard because I cannot find out general formula for such number in terms of $k$. Computing manually is also not possible because there are too many candidates for $k$. ($0 \sim \lfloor \frac{2008^3}{2009} \rfloor$)

Thank you for any form of hint, help, or solution.

Answer (score 4):

The $k$th term of $A$ can be written as

$$\left\lfloor\frac{k^3}{2009}\right\rfloor
= \frac{k^3 - \left(k^3\bmod 2009\right)}{2009}$$

So the whole sum $A$ is

$$\begin{align*}
A &= \sum_{k=1}^{2008} \left\lfloor\frac{k^3}{2009}\right\rfloor\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{2008} \frac{k^3 - \left(k^3\bmod 2009\right)}{2009}\\
&= \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{2008} k^3}{2009} - \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{2008} \left(k^3\bmod 2009\right)}{2009} \tag1
\end{align*}$$

The sum of cubes is well-known:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{2008} k^3}{2009}
&= \frac{2008^2 \cdot (2008+1)^2}{2^2\cdot 2009}\\
&= 1004^2\cdot 2009 \tag2
\end{align*}$$

For the sum of remainders in $(1)$, by factorising $2009 = 7\cdot 7\cdot 41$, for integer $k$,

$$2009 \mid k^3
\iff 7\cdot 41 = \frac{2009}7 \mid k^3$$

and consider the remainders of $k^3$ and $(2009-k)^3$,

$$\begin{align*}
k^3 + (2009-k)^3 \equiv k^3 + (-k)^3 &\equiv 0 \pmod{2009}\\
\left(k^3 \bmod 2009\right) + \left((2009-k)^3 \bmod 2009\right)
&= \begin{cases}
0, & 2009\mid k^3\\
2009, & 2009 \nmid k^3
\end{cases}\\
&= \begin{cases}
0, & \frac{2009}7 \mid k\\
2009, & \frac{2009}7 \nmid k
\end{cases}\\
\end{align*}$$

So the terms of $\sum_{k=1}^{2008} \left(k^3\bmod 2009\right)$ pair up, with $6$ terms of zero while other pairs each add to $2009$:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{2008} \left(k^3\bmod 2009\right)
&= \frac{2008-6}{2} \cdot 2009\\
\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{2008} \left(k^3\bmod 2009\right)}{2009}
&= 1001 \tag3
\end{align*}$$

From $(2)$ and $(3)$,

$$\begin{align*}
A
= 1004^2 \cdot 2009 - 1001
&\equiv 4^2 \cdot 9 - 1\\
&\equiv 143 \pmod{1000}
\end{align*}$$

(Recording my comments under [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4859661/89922) as a post)

Answer (score 2):

Let $\{x\} = x - \lfloor x \rfloor \in [0,1)$ be the fractional number of $x$.

For any integer $1 \le k \le 1004$, $2009$ divides $k^3 + (2009-k)^3$ and hence $\frac{k^3}{2009} + \frac{(2009-k)^3}{2009}$ is an integer. This implies

$$\small \left\{\frac{k^3}{2009}\right\} + \left\{\frac{(2009-k)^3}{2009}\right\}
= \frac{k^3}{2009} + \frac{(2009-k)^3}{2009}
- \left\lfloor\frac{k^3}{2009}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor\frac{(2009-k)^3}{2009}\right\rfloor\tag{*1}$$
is an integer in $[0,2)$. ie.  it equals to either $0$ or $1$.

In order for it to be $0$, we need $\left\{\frac{k^3}{2009}\right\} = \left\{\frac{(2009-k)^3}{2009}\right\} = 0$.
This is equivalent to $2009| k^3$. Since $2009 = 7^2\cdot 41$, this reduces to $284|k$.
For $1 \le k \le 1004$, there are only three such $k: 284,568,852$.

Summing $(*1)$ from $k = 0$ to $1004$ and rearrange, we get

$$\begin{align}
A = \sum_{k=1}^{2008} \left\lfloor \frac{k^3}{2009}\right\rfloor
&= \sum_{k=1}^{2008} \frac{k^3}{2009} - (1004 - 3)\\
&= \frac1{2009}\left(\frac{2008(2008+1)}{2}\right)^2 - 1001\\
&= 2009(1004)^2 - 1001\\
\end{align}$$

So the remainder is
$$A \equiv 9(4)^2 - 1 \equiv 143 \pmod{1000}$$

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you might be able to find a general form for
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k^3}{2009}.
\end{equation*}
Fixing $n=2008$ might help thereafter. Modular arithmetic should quickly deal with the fractional part. Let me know if this is too vague of a hint.

Comment: I'd like to see details of how "modular arithmetic should quickly deal with the fractional part".  It doesn't look so quick to me, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: How can I deal with the fractional part? I should compute $k^3$ mod 2009 for each $k$, but I don't know how to calculate such things. The fact that $2009 = 7\cdot7\cdot41$ (not a prime) confuses me even more.

Comment: @mathhello I can see that $2008^3\bmod 2009 = (-1)^3\bmod 2009 = 2008$, to match with $1^3\bmod 2009$. But how many of the cubes are divisible by $2009$ will need more thinking.

Comment: @mathhello From the factorisation, cubes of multiples of $7\cdot 41 = 2009/7$ are divisible by $2009$. So $\sum_{k=1}^{2008}(k^3\bmod 2009)$ are $\dfrac{2008-6}2$ pairs of terms that add to $2009$.

Comment: @peterwhy, that’s pretty clever, so the sum would always be $2009\cdot 1001$ even if it were some other odd power of $k$ in the summation. What if the power was even though? Could anything be done then?